# Crear una matriz y encontrar el valor mayor de cada fila y columna

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Tengo una duda en un programa
Basicamente el programa dice lo siguiente:
Encontrar el valor mas grande de cada fila,de cada columna y el mayor de toda la matriz,es una matriz de 4x7.
En realidad el programa es un menu con mas opciones pero yo ya tengo todas, solamente que no se como encontrar el valor mas grande de la fila y columna,el valor mayor de toda la matriz tambien me sale el unico problema es con las columnas y filas.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ULTIMOEXAMEN
{
    class Examen
    {
        public float[,] matriz;


        public void iniciar()
        {
            matriz = new float[4, 7];
            for (int f = 0; f < 4; f++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < 7; c++)
                {
                    Console.Write("Ingrese posicion [" + (f + 1) + "," + (c + 1) + "]: ");
                    string linea;
                    linea = Console.ReadLine();
                    matriz[f, c] = float.Parse(linea);
                }
            }


        }
        public void menu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ELEGIR UNA OPCION: ");
            Console.WriteLine("1- SUMAS");
            Console.WriteLine("2- MAYOR");
            Console.WriteLine("3- ESCALAR");
            Console.WriteLine("4- SALIR");

            switch (Console.Read())
            {
                case '1':
                    //SUMA DE FILAS
                    for (int f = 0; f < 4; f++)
                    {
                        float suma = 0;
                        for (int c = 0; c < 7; c++)
                        {
                            suma += matriz[f, c];
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("FILA " + f + " = " + suma);
                    }
                    //SUMA DE COLUMNAS

                    for (int c = 0; c < 7; c++)
                    {
                        float suma = 0;
                        for (int f = 0; f < 4; f++)
                        {
                            suma += matriz[f, c];
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("COLUMNA " + c + " = " + suma);
                    }

                    break;

                case '2':

                    //EL MAYOR DE TODA LA MATRIZ
                    float mayortodo = 0;
                    float mayor = matriz[0, 0];
                    for (int f = 0; f < 4; f++)
                    {
                        for (int c = 0; c < 7; c++)
                        {
                            if (matriz[f, c] > mayortodo)
                            {

                                mayor = matriz[f, c];
                                mayortodo = mayor;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("EL ELEMENTO MAYOR DE LA MATRIZ ES:" + mayortodo);

                    //EL  MAYOR DE CADA FILA
                    float mayorfila = 0;
                    float mayor2 = matriz[0,0];
                    for( int f=0; f<4; f++)
                    {
                        for (int c=0; c<7; c++)
                        {
                            if(matriz[f,c]>mayorfila)
                            {
                                mayor2 = matriz[f, c];
                                mayorfila = mayor2;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("EL ELEMENTO MAYOR DE LA FILA ES: " + mayorfila);
                    break;

                case '3':
                    break;

                case '4':
                    System.Environment.Exit(4);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;
            }

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Examen ex = new Examen();
            ex.iniciar();
            ex.menu();
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Pasa el titulo a minúsculas que parece que estas gritando

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien, necesitas imprimir en la consola el numero mayor de cada fila:

```
               //EL  MAYOR DE CADA FILA

                for(int f = 0; f < 4; f++)
                {
                    // el mayor va a cambiar por fila, lo podemos definir aqui
                    float mayorfila = 0;    // buffer para guardar el mayor
                    for (int c = 0;  c < 7; c++)
                    {
                        // actualizamos el mayor con el nuevo mayor que encontramos
                        if(matriz[f,c]>mayorfila)
                        {
                            mayorfila = matriz[f, c];
                        }
                    } 
                    // aqui ya terminamos la fila, entonces podemos imprimir
                    Console.WriteLine("EL ELEMENTO MAYOR DE LA FILA ES: " + mayorfila);
                }
```